# segmentation fault: while bubble sort of arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bubble-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    int data[] = {1, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8};
    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++)
        for ( j = 0; j < sizeof(data) - 1; j++)
            if (data[j] > data[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = data[j];
                data[j] = data[j + 1];
                data[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints `segmentation fault` when run,can someone please help me to find out what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
sizeof(data)
```

In the condition of all the `for` loops to

```
sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])
```

This is done because `sizeof(int-array)` is the number of elements in the array **multiplied with the `sizeof(int)`**(which is usually 4 bytes). `sizeof(data[0])` is the same as `sizeof(int)` as `data[0]` is an `int.` So, you can also use

```
sizeof(data)/sizeof(int)
```

In the condition of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of an object in *bytes*, not the number of elements in it.

For example in your code, `sizeof(data)` will return `24` because there are 6 elements in the array, each taking 4 bytes (the size of `int`).

---

To get the number of elements in an array, divide the size of the array in bytes by the size of one element in it:

```
sizeof(data) / sizeof(int)
```

---

(As a side note, that's not a binary search.)

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to compute the number of elements in an array with a macro like

```
#define ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(array)  (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
```

and then use

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(data); i++)
```

to iterate over all elements. This is almost self-documenting.

Note that this only works for array identifiers, not for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `sizeof(data)` is `24`(it is based on the sizeof integer). But the array have the limit upto `6` only.

So it leads to array out of bounds and segmentation fault. so change that for loop
as like this, in both the loops.

```
 for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++)
```

Or else

```
 for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) // 6 is no of values placed in that array
```

Comment: `sizeof(data)` is 48 here on my big iron... don't make assumptions.

Comment: No in my system it gave 24. So I done that. And it is not a assumption.